# how to show only particular category post in archive widgets

Tags: widgets, archives

i want to display blog category month list in archive widgets. but i i can't figure out yet how. i have more category like review, gallery etc. normally show all month list in archive widgets but i want only BLOG show in archive widgets. i already figure our how to show only blog post in archive page but now problem is widgets. any idea guys how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
add_filter( 'getarchives_join' , 'getarchives_join_filter');
function getarchives_join_filter( $join ) {
    global $wpdb;
    return $join . " INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} tr ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = tr.object_id) INNER JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} tt ON (tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id)";
}

add_filter( 'getarchives_where' , 'getarchives_where_filter');
function getarchives_where_filter( $where ) {
    global $wpdb;


    return $where . " AND tt.taxonomy = 'category' AND tt.term_id='blog category id' ";

    }
```

Change 'blog category id' with your blog category id.

Comment: wow..... its working nice... thanks @rajeev vyas.. thanks you so much..